# Running a Raspberry Pi off of a Wii Balance Board

Tags: hardware, battery

I am working on an internet connected scale. I want it to theoretically run forever without my intervention so I picked up [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004BY4HN2) battery pack for my balance board. I plan on having the board constantly connected to the wall via the USB cable. It says that the battery pack was LiPo Batteries and I was wondering if it was reasonable for me to power the Raspberry Pi off of it too, I'm worried there won't be enough power left over for the Pi. If so, would I need a voltage regulator (any suggestions on what kind)? Ideally, I only want to connect one cable to the outlet, and if I was able to put the Raspberry Pi inside the case it would be a more compact/pretty solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to know for sure, but I highly doubt it.  That's a pretty small battery (700mAh), it gives us no indication as to how much power it outputs, and it doesn't look like there's a built in way in which you could divert power from it to the RPi and Wii board simultaneously.